# Plotting multiple variables in matplotlib python

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot a bar graph, and I have multiple lists for xaxisn (n from 1 to 5) and yaxisn (1 to 5).  The values in each respective xaxisn were originally mapped to the values in yaxisn in a dictionary, and they are the same from 1 to 5 but in different order. For example

```
dict1 = {'a': 80, 'c': 30, 'e': 52, 'b': 12, 'd': 67}
dict2 = {'c': 47, 'a': 73, 'e': 32, 'd': 35, 'b': 40}
```

So I created a list containing all the nominal values for x and tried to plot everything together with

```
xaxis = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
yaxis1 = dict1.values()
xaxis1 = dict1.keys()
yaxis2 = dict2.values()
xaxis2 = dict2.keys()
plt.bar(xaxis1,yaxis1)
plt.bar(xaxis2,yaxis2)
plt.xticks(range(len(xaxis)),xaxis)
```

but I've noticed that despite being mapped together, the y values in the graph aren't aligned to the right x. So instead of showing, in order the frequencies for `xaxis`, they keep the same order as in the dictionary.
I have tried to change the last line of code into

```
plt.xticks(range(len(xaxis)),xaxis1)
plt.xticks(range(len(xaxis)),xaxis2)
```

but again, with multiple variables, one overwrites the previous one.
Do I need to order all the dictionaries the same way to plot them, or is there another way to do it without having to redo all my codes?

Comment: You could always plot sorted versions of your dictionaries `dict1_sorted = {k: v for k, v in sorted(dict1.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}`

Comment: @Taxel based on what does it sort it?

Comment: @Taxel the actual keys that I have do not really have an order, does it work with them too?

Comment: It should sort them lexically, so "a", "asd", "b"... - as long as your keys are strings, this should work fine.

Comment: [`The sort routines are guaranteed to use __lt__() when making comparisons between two objects`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#odd-and-ends) -  if your key objects support *less-than* comparison you can sort `dict1.items()` and `dict2.items()` to ensure order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ensure that the order for the two y axes are the same by using the keys of one dict to extract the values from both. Here is one way to do it.

```
import operator

dict1 = {'a': 80, 'c': 30, 'e': 52, 'b': 12, 'd': 67}
dict2 = {'c': 47, 'a': 73, 'e': 32, 'd': 35, 'b': 40}

xs = dict1.keys()
f = operator.itemgetter(*xs)
y1 = f(dict1)
y2 = f(dict2)

>>> xs
dict_keys(['a', 'c', 'e', 'b', 'd'])
>>> y1
(80, 30, 52, 12, 67)
>>> y2
(73, 47, 32, 40, 35)
>>>
```

Then use `xs` for all the plotting.

```
plt.bar(xs,y1)
plt.bar(xs,y2)
plt.xticks(range(len(xs)),xs)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) will *get* each item it is *instantiated* with in the order they were given. Similar to these list comprehensions.

```
>>> [dict1[k] for k in xs]
[80, 30, 52, 12, 67]
>>> [dict2[k] for k in xs]
[73, 47, 32, 40, 35]
>>>
```

Comment: Just to double check, could you briefly explain the function of the package operator? As it's my first time seeing it

Comment: From what I understand, f is a way to reorder the dictionaries based on key order. What I don't get is `y1=f(dict1)` Does this only change the order or also specify that y1 only cares for the values?

Comment: @jfilenxd845 - see edit. It doesn't reorder the dictionaries, it retrieves the values in a specific order.

Comment: So is saying `y1=f(dict1)` or `y1=f(dict1).values()` the same in this case?

Comment: Also, I have just noticed that one of the dictionaries is missing a key, I've tried to create a for loop to avoid getting an error when this happens but it's not working. What would you do?

Comment: @jfilenxd845 - `y1=f(dict1).values()` - did you try that? I imagine that would give you an attribute error, `f(dict1)` returns a list. Everything in my answer assumes the same keys are present in both dictionaries - you didn't specify otherwise in your question. If that isn't the case, you could create a for loop similar to the list comprehensions and either use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) or [handle the Exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).